# AccessDenied when view image after upload Parse.com

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com for store my image. In client I use NodeJs to upload.

Image has uploaded succesfully and save to parse database.

But when I click to image, this show error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>C449B7B4A8AEA4C8</RequestId>
<HostId>
RzKG+RkaYS2FA6e7+09sZxNejJdwmVGq+B9W/XzYNkuOFVs0nnwVze6fj6JVH6tN9WopLfQInB4=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Please give me advice about it.

This is my code in client for upload file

```
app.post('/upload', function(request, response) {

parse.insertFile('haha', request.file, 'image/jpg', function(error, response) {
    console.log(response);
    parse.insert('Image',{'Image': {'__type' : 'File', 'name': response.name + '.jpg' } }, function (error, response) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

});

Data will be insert to table Image, field Image. And it already inserted.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some more code, so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: I already add it. Please help me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem when I cant see the image is the image I have uploaded is failed. So I cant not see it.

Just implement again function upload to parse.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, how did you solve this? I have the same problem but only after switching to the open source parse-server code for uploading files.